# Error when removing column in strongly-typed dataset?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, strongly-typed-dataset

When I retrieve data into my `DataSet`, the `year` column is the 3rd column in my `DataSet`.  I do not need this column after using it do so some calculations, so I remove it using the `Remove` method passing the column's name to the `Remove` method.  The problem is that I retrieve the data in a `foreach` loop, so when I retrieve the data again, the `year` column is now the last column in the `DataSet` and when I try to access it, it throws an error saying `year` column was not found.  My way around this was to clone by `DataSet` into a `DataTable` and then to import each row from the dataset into my `DataTable`, but is there a more efficient way or a way to keep the `year` column in it's original position.

```
private int GetData()
{
    dataSet.GetExportData();

    DataTable dt = dataSet.ExportData;

    for(int i = 0; i <dataSet.ExportData; i++)
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }

    dataSet.Columns.Remove(dataSet.ExportData.YearColumn.ColumnName);   
}
```

In the above code, when I open up a dialog and select data to export, it works the first time, but if I leave the dialog open and click the button to export again, it throws the error.  If I close the dialog and reopen, it works fine.  As I said before I noticed when it retrieves the data again on the button click with `dataSet.GetExportData()`, it puts the `Year` column as the last column instead of the defined position in the strongly-typed `DataSet` which I assume is the problem, but can't figure out how to fix it besides doing a Clone and Import.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the column within the foreach loop, and again retrieve the value of the column? could you post some code?

Comment: @CjCoax - Yes, I don't have code with me right now, but will post it later, but what you said is exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to be in comment, but I want to take advantage of code styling, also it's hard to say what exactly you want to achieve without sighting the code,

```
    foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
    {
        //do something with year column 
        myTable.Columns.Remove("year");
    }
```

above code works fine in the first iteration, but will fail afterwards, as `myTable.Columns.Remove("year")` removes the whole column, from the table not just from current row, and gives you: `You'll get Column 'year' does not belong to table Table.`exception.

Why not taking `myTable.Columns.Remove("year");` out of the foreach instead?

```
    foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
    {
        //do something with year column 
    }

    myTable.Columns.Remove("year");
```

Comment: Sorry, I spoke to soon. The data is not retrieved in a foreach loop, I will post some code.